# Search option in select menu Jquery-Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a select menu of jquery-mobile in my project. Now the list is so large and i have to put search option in it for filtering. I searched it in jquery mobile but did not find the solution in it. Please help me and let me know is it possible or not.

Answer (score 3):

It can be done, take a look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/sEMyT/2/

Source code can be found here: https://github.com/aliok/jquery-mobile/commits/selectmenu-forceDialog/

Code example:

```
        <a href="#" onclick="$('#select-choice-12').selectmenu('refresh', true); return false;">Refresh the selectmenu (forcerebuild) with clearing the filter value</a>

                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="select-choice-12" class="select">Your state:</label>
                    <select name="select-choice-12" id="select-choice-12" data-native-menu="false" data-force-dialog="true" data-native-menu="false" data-filter="true">
                        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                        <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                        <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
                        <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
                        <option value="CA">California</option>
                        <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
                        <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
                        <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
                        <option value="FL">Florida</option>
                        <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
                        <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
                        <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
                        <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
                        <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
                        <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
                        <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
                        <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
                        <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
                        <option value="ME">Maine</option>
                        <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
                        <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
                        <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
                        <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
                        <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
                        <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
                        <option value="MT">Montana</option>
                        <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
                        <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
                        <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
                        <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
                        <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
                        <option value="NY">New York</option>
                        <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
                        <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
                        <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
                        <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
                        <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
                        <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
                        <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
                        <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
                        <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
                        <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
                        <option value="TX">Texas</option>
                        <option value="UT">Utah</option>
                        <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
                        <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
                        <option value="WA">Washington</option>
                        <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
                        <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
                        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
    You can see the source code at <a href="https://github.com/aliok/jquery-mobile/commits/selectmenu-forceDialog/">https://github.com/aliok/jquery-mobile/commits/selectmenu-forceDialog/</a>
```

Comment: Dear Gajotres,
Thank you so much for your reply. The solution you have given me is the 3rd party js. But i am looking for The code form the jquery-mobile itself.

Comment: You will not find it because it don't exist. Official jQuery Mobile offers filtering only to listview. You can always use listview component instead of select box, but you will still need to modify it with custom check box.

Comment: did not work for me with the jquery.mobile-1.3.2 and jquery-1.9.1